# Wordpress update field inside "set_object_terms" hook function

Tags: php, wordpress

**Bonjour!**

I am trying to rewrite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079535/automatically-check-child-categories-terms-when-parent-category-is-checked) custom `set_object_terms` hook function.
What I am trying to achieve in addition to **Automatically check child categories/terms when parent category is checked** as this function already is doing, is to also update the GeoDirectory field `post_category` with the same data as the updated values for: `$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'gd_placecategory' );`

Note that Geo Directory has it own set of get/delete/save functions, I have tested them from a template . What I have tried in order to solve this issue is to create an `$merge` and `$diff` variable for add and remove, and then trying to add this to the `post_category` field by using the `geodir_save_post_meta()` function. I have also tried to perform the update by using the `$wpdb->update()` as well.

```
        .
        .
        .
        .


// Any terms ADDED this time?
if( !empty($added_terms) ){
    $add = array();

    foreach( $added_terms as $added_term ){

        // Do any of these added terms have children?
        if( $added_child_terms = get_term_children( $added_term, $taxonomy ) ){
            // Append those children
            wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $added_child_terms, $taxonomy, true );
            $add[] = $added_child_terms;
        }
    }

    if( !empty($add) ){

        $add = $add[0];
        $merge = array_merge($old_tt_ids,$add);  
        $merge = implode(",",$merge);

        if( !empty($merge) ){

            geodir_save_post_meta($object_id, 'post_category', $merge);
            //$wpdb->update( 'wp_geodir_gd_subscription_detail', array( 'post_category' => $merge), array('post_id' => $object_id ));

        }
    }
}

// Any terms REMOVED?
if( !empty($removed_terms) ){
     $remove = array();

    foreach( $removed_terms as $removed_terms ){

        // Do any of the removed terms have children?
        if( $removed_child_terms = get_term_children( $removed_terms, $taxonomy ) ){
            // Remove them all
            wp_remove_object_terms( $object_id, $removed_child_terms, $taxonomy, true );
            $remove[] = $removed_child_terms;
        }
    }

    if( !empty($remove) ){

        $remove = $remove[0];    
        $diff = array_diff($old_tt_ids,$remove);  
        $diff = implode(",",$diff);

        if( !empty($diff) ){

            geodir_save_post_meta($object_id, 'post_category', $diff );
            //$wpdb->update( 'wp_geodir_gd_subscription_detail', array( 'post_category' => $diff), array('post_id' => $object_id ));

        }
    }

}
```

When either the `geodir_save_post_meta()` function or the `$wpdb->update()` is added to the function, this custom function does run, but only the terms are changed. None of the `set_object_terms` generated terms is added to the `post_category` field.

It seems to me that the `set_object_terms` hook is not the place to run a update from. Still I need this hook to perform the **Automatically check child categories/terms when parent category is checked**.

How can I both **Automatically check child categories/terms when parent category is checked** and update the GeoDirectory field `post_category` at the same time?

Comment: So you have code that is working, and you put more code inside that makes the whole thing stop working? This almost always means that there is an error in the inserted code. Make sure you have errors completely turned on and set to screaming.

Comment: Correction (updated): the function is actually running, but the only the "default" Wordpress terms is changed, noting is added to the post_category. BTW, WP_DEBUG is turned on.

Comment: Okay. I would next to a dump/print on `$merge` and `$diff` and see if those hold what you expect them to. If they do, the problem is obviously with the insert, if they don't the problem is before. Also, both `add` and `remove` are arrays that are appended to in a `for` loop, but then you just throw away everything except the first item by doing `$remove = $remove[0]`, is that intentional?

Comment: I don't know why, but both `add` and `remove` becomes [[123, 345,678]] so I had to `[0]` to get to the values for the merge and diff functions. I checked, both `$merge` and `$diff` hold expected values.

Comment: @Xhynk you made this piece of code I am trying to customize, do you happen to have any suggestions that could point me in the correct direction regarding this Wordpress GeoDirectory issue?